# Action Prefix to ASP.NET MVC Routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, routes, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

I would like to set up a route that submits to a controller with a prefixed action.

For example, I have a `ProvidersController` for service providers, and I have a `ProviderType` model that I'd like to handle within the Providers controller (it's a lightweight object and I just assume not set up new controllers specifically for each of these little supporting objects, thus I want to group them into the Providers controller).

So, my `ProvidersController` has standard actions for managing providers:

```
public class ProvidersController : ControllerBase
{
    public ActionResult Index() { }
    public ActionResult Create() { }
    public ActionResult Edit(int id) { }
    // ect ect
}
```

I'd like to handle ProviderTypes in here as well:

```
public class ProvidersController : ControllerBase
{
    public ActionResult Index() { }
    public ActionResult Create() { }
    public ActionResult Edit(int id) { }
    // ect ect
    public ActionResult TypeIndex() { }
    public ActionResult TypeCreate() { }
    public ActionResult TypeEdit(int id) { }
    // ect ect
}
```

This is all fine, expect I want my routing to "look like" a Type is nested:

```
~/Providers/Create
~/Providers/Types/Create
```

Here's a route I had in mind:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ProviderTypes",
    url: "Providers/Types/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Providers", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

But this would require I use a `~/Providers/Types/TypeCreate` route, which I don't like.

Is there some way I can "intercept" this route and add a "Type" prefix to the action so it maps to the controller action correctly but provides a clean URL the way I'd like?

E.g., how would I get `~/Providers/Types/Create` to map to `ProvidersController.TypeCreate()`?

(as a general note, I'm trying to avoid attribute routing as I like to have all my route definitions coming from one place instead of scattered throughout)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could enable [ASP.NET MVC Attribute Routing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/)

in `RouteConfig.cs`

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes){
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    //enabling attribute routing
    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

    //You can also combine attribute routing with convention-based routing.
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Then in your `ProvidersController`

```
[RoutePrefix("Providers"]
public class ProvidersController : ControllerBase {
    //eg: GET Providers
    [Route("")]
    public ActionResult Index() {...}
    //eg: GET Providers/Create
    [Route("Create")]
    public ActionResult Create() {...}
    //eg: GET Providers/Edit/5
    [Route("Edit/{id:int}")]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id) {...}
    // ...

    //eg: GET Providers/Types
    [Route("Types")]
    public ActionResult TypeIndex() {...}
    //eg: GET Providers/Types/Create
    [Route("Types/Create")]
    public ActionResult TypeCreate() {...}
    //eg: GET Providers/Types/Edit/5
    [Route("Types/Edit/{id:int}")]
    public ActionResult TypeEdit(int id) {...}
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, though I prefer to avoid attribute routing (note added to original question).  If need be I suppose I could use attribute routing only for the "special" actions...

Answer (score 1):

Though intensive, it is possible. You would have to enter all the routes manually to get what you desire, which would defeat the purpose of having the conventions.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ProviderTypes",
    url: "Providers/Types",
    defaults: new { controller = "Providers", action = "TypeIndex" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ProviderTypes_Create",
    url: "Providers/Types/Create",
    defaults: new { controller = "Providers", action = "TypeCreate" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ProviderTypes_Edit",
    url: "Providers/Types/Edit/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Providers", action = "TypeEdit", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
//....
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use [MvcCodeRouting](http://mvccoderouting.codeplex.com/), which actually *would* nest your controllers into a hierarchy. Then you could separate your `Providers` and `Types` into individual controllers that are logically nested.

```
> MyNamespace.Controllers.Providers.ProvidersController
    > MyNamespace.Controllers.Providers.TypesController
```

The result is getting URLs that are nested based on your controller namespaces.

- /Providers/{action}
- /Providers/Types/{action}

See [Controllers and Namespaces](https://github.com/maxtoroq/MvcCodeRouting/blob/master/docs/Controllers-and-Namespaces.md) for more information.